# Displaying a float value in a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

Here is the point:

I would like to display the result of a mathematic algorithm (division) on a QLineEdit:

I take a pixel of an image (coordinates : i and j) and I divide it by 255

```
CvScalar scal = cvGet2D(img,j,i);    
float s= scal.val[2]*(1/255);
Qs = QString::number( s, 'g', 6 );
lineEdit->setText(Qs);
```

The problem is that, instead of showing me the precision of this division (0.xxxx), the result is just a 0 without the float that I need to display.

Do you have any idea how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 4):

1/255 is **0** integer. Replace by **1.0**/255

Answer (score 0):

`1/255` - is an **integer** division. Write `1.0/255.0` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace `1/255` with `1/255.0f`.
It is more elegant and gives you clear view that you want float value.
Another ways are: `1.0f/255`, `((float)1)/255`.

Comment: The most elegant way to do that is: `1/255.0f`.